# Are user-uploaded .svg's a XSS risk? How can you "sterilize" an SVG?

Tags: svg, xss, raphael

We have a website that allows users to design graphics, and one of the things we support is SVGs.  We want to allow users to upload SVGs, but are concerned with the potential for abuse (including code in the .SVG file).

Is there a way to sterilize .svg files?

Answer (score 2):

If you display the uploaded svg data as images i.e. `<img src="uploadedFile.svg">` in html then UAs won't run any scripts.

Comment: but should the user choose "open in new tab" for the malicious svg or download and open the image locally, then all scripts will run.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing svg upload is similar to allowing html upload, so you will need a similar level of checking the files. See e.g the [html5lib sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/).

Comment: And how is one supposed to use that library to allow safe SVG uploads? I'm seeing an HTML parser but no obvious "use this for file uploads" or "sanitize your user's HTML with this" functions. Please add an explanation to link-only answers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, user-uploaded SVG files can include JavaScript. These execute if you load that image directly (top-level navigation). Someone could be sent a link to check out a funny meme on your website, and unwittingly be running scripts in your website's context in the background.

Modern browsers do not execute scripts inside of `<img>` tags, so `<img src='/uploads/4bafa902.svg'>` is safe. However, sending someone a link to `https://example.com/uploads/4bafa902.svg` **will** execute scripts if they click it. Imagine a Discord user would get a link leading to `discord.com/.../some-image.svg`. They probably think it safe to click.

Even if your session ID cookie has `HttpOnly` set and cannot be accessed, and even with `SameSite` in use, the browser will still attach it to any requests coming from the right origin. Because the SVG is hosted on your own website, you will be meeting the origin policy. Or if anyone has your domain in their CORS allow list header, that SVG can now make requests to that website as well. Either unwanted actions could be performed, or obtained data could be sent back to the attacker.

**To safely host SVG images,** you need to either:

- Have a `Content-Security-Policy` (CSP) response header set on SVG images which denies running those scripts. This is the one I use:

  ```
  Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; report-uri /cspreport
  ```
- Remove/sanitize the executable contents from an untrusted SVG, either before hosting it or before serving the contents to users.

Both options have caveats:

The CSP header is often configured globally on the web server. If you set a custom one for SVG content responses, that might be overridden by the web server (either replaced, or two might be set in a random order and lead to unexpected results).

The cleaning/sanitizing is prone to oversights, and you also need to keep up with new (and perhaps obscure) browser features, similar to how `ontouchstart` was defined for touchscreen devices only in 2013, nearly twenty years after [`onclick` was defined](https://docs.stendahls.net/js/netscape/evnt5.htm#1010516) (maybe VR/AR headsets will get their own events for *looking at* an element, or something else we do not have yet today). Thus, I would not try to build my own, but rather trust to a project that focuses on cleaning SVGs against XSS such as [DOMPurifier](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify).

Having both defences probably gets you the best of both worlds: if the purifier is circumvented, the CSP should still prevent execution, and vice versa.